# EB Worker cron.yaml - is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:UpdateItem

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been trying to implement a cron job on my EB worker.

My EB CLI on a deploy says "ERROR: Update environment operation is complete, but with errors."

My yaml seems to parse just fine and in my EB events list I see the line "Successfully loaded 1 scheduled tasks from cron.yaml."

```
version: 1
cron:
 - name: "cron"
   url: "/cron"
   schedule: "* * * * *"
```

I look in the eb-activity.log and there is this issue:

```
Activity execution failed, because: User: arn:aws:sts::550612933446:assumed-role/WorkerTierRole_KK/i-5fe79aa0 is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:UpdateItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:550612933446:table/awseb-e-jcrjmidtsu-stack-AWSEBWorkerCronLeaderRegistry-1GVA6A4AV0YDW - (Aws::DynamoDB::Errors::AccessDeniedException) (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: User: arn:aws:sts::550612933446:assumed-role/WorkerTierRole_KK/i-5fe79aa0 is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:UpdateItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:550612933446:table/awseb-e-jcrjmidtsu-stack-AWSEBWorkerCronLeaderRegistry-1GVA6A4AV0YDW - (Aws::DynamoDB::Errors::AccessDeniedException) (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

This is what I also found in the log:

```
2015-06-04T02:17:19Z schedule-parser: Successfully loaded 1 scheduled tasks from file /opt/python/current/app/cron.yaml .
2015-06-04T02:17:19Z init: User: arn:aws:sts::550612933446:assumed-role/WorkerTierRole_KK/i-254d00f5 is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:UpdateItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:550612933446:table/awseb-e-jcrjmidtsu-stack-AWSEBWorkerCronLeaderRegistry-1KMJ9BLOVIUSJ (Aws::DynamoDB::Errors::AccessDeniedException)
    at /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.0.10/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:15:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.0.10/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/dynamodb_simple_attributes.rb:112:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.0.10/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/param_conversion.rb:22:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.0.10/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/response_paging.rb:10:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.0.10/lib/seahorse/client/request.rb:70:in `send_request'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.0.10/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:215:in `block (2 levels) in define_operation_methods'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sqsd-2.0/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election/storage_manager.rb:81:in `update_registration'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sqsd-2.0/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election/storage_manager.rb:19:in `verify_table'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sqsd-2.0/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election/daemon.rb:37:in `initialize'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sqsd-2.0/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election.rb:8:in `new'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sqsd-2.0/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election.rb:8:in `create'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sqsd-2.0/lib/aws-sqsd/cron.rb:241:in `leader_election_daemon'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sqsd-2.0/lib/aws-sqsd/cron.rb:30:in `initialize'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sqsd-2.0/lib/aws-sqsd/daemon.rb:44:in `new'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sqsd-2.0/lib/aws-sqsd/daemon.rb:44:in `initialize'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sqsd-2.0/bin/aws-sqsd:34:in `new'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sqsd-2.0/bin/aws-sqsd:34:in `start'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sqsd-2.0/bin/aws-sqsd:83:in `launch'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sqsd-2.0/bin/aws-sqsd:111:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/aws-sqsd:23:in `load'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/aws-sqsd:23:in `<main>'
```

I have tried rebuilding my environment but that didn't make any difference.

It seems like this error is out of my hands (hope that is not the case and I have made a simple mistake) and is an EB issue with how it handles cron jobs. I don't have any dynamodb's :)

Many thanks for any help,
Phil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cron worker uses a small dynamo db table behind the scenes  to ensure only one instance in your auto scaling group executes the cron task. Hence you need to update your role policy to include relevant dynamo db permissions.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It's showing an error `is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:UpdateItem`. I have permission and I've created a DynamoDB table to test it. What more should I be able to do? I am not the owner, so he is creating the role for me. When I tried to create my own it gives me an error... Is there a specific permission that he needs to set? Which one it is? Thank you so much

Comment: The permission needs to be on the role linked to your IAM instance profile which you are using for the environment. Are you saying you have permission for your IAM user or IAM instance profile? The instance profile role is typically named "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role" (could be different if you created a role with a different name).
Check permissions required on IAM instance profile here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts-roles.html#concepts-roles-instance

Comment: I could add the permission and it's running now. Thank you so much! However the command is not running. The health is severe almost all the time. At the log file the access log prints this: `"POST /myapp/management/commands/delete_expired_files HTTP/1.1" 500 124709 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.0"` several times. The command is supposed to delete some files, seems like its running but the files are not being deleted... do you have any clue? Thanks, I've been struggling with this for 2 weeks... you helped me so much, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad it worked! The health of your environment is Severe because as your HTTP POST message shows, your application is returning HTTP 500 response codes. There can be other reasons for severe health but given the data, this is what it appears to be. You need to look at your applications logs to find out why delete_expired_files is failing. You can add additional logging to your application to see where it is failing. Probably it is throwing an uncaught exception, that's why you are getting internal server error in your proxy logs. Can you ssh to your instance & see your application logs?

Comment: I have access to the log file at my application environment console. There are two environments running the same application, one is the worker tier and the other one is hosting the application. At the worker tier I have this below the **/var/log/aws-sqsd/default.log**: `message: sent to %[http://localhost:80/myapp/management/commands/delete_expired_files]
2016-01-17T13:19:04Z http-err: c2de29b1-1b34-48d6-8404-9f9aa00a3949 (3) 500 - 0.285`. Doest this helps?

Comment: Actually this is just the worker tier daemon logging that it got an HTTP 500 response from your application. You need to add logging to your application where you implement delete_expired_files to see why it fails. Do you have logging configured in your source code? Where do you log stuff?

Comment: Which solution stack are you using? You need to log something in your application then configure beanstalk to capture your logs. You can create log files in /var/log in your application source code then get full logs (not just snapshot) from the environment dashboard

Comment: I have no clue about how to do it. I don't use `eb cli` or anything related to AWS. The command worked locally using `python manage.py delete_expired_files`. I've adapted it to run it at ElasticBeansTalk... Are you suggesting I create a log inside of my delete_expired_files function? This is the log file I know how to access: [https://docs.google.com/document/d/1l43uPtkMooywaH5L-Hk4kpv81faeJQFuNnVDieGIDXE/edit?usp=sharing]... I've also created another question at stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34830428/aws-worker-tier-cron-server-error-500-post-http-1-1-500-aws-aws-sqsd-2-0

Comment: Yes you should create log from your delete_expired_files function to see if it is being executed or not. If it is being executed the logs will tell you with what error it is failing. I will follow up on the other question.