# AWS Worker tier cron - server error #500 - "post http 1.1 500 AWS aws-sqsd/2.0"

Tags: django, http, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to set up a cronjob at Elastic Beanstalk. The task is being scheduled. For testing purposes it should run every minute... However it is not working. It is a Django app. The app is running in two Environments, one is the worker and the other one is "hosting" the application.

This part is working. The command is running but it's not being executed (the files are not being deleted).

Here is **views.py**:

`@login_required
def delete_expired_files(request):
    users = DemoUser.objects.all()
    for user in users:
        documents = Document.objects.filter(owner=user.id)
        if documents:
            for doc in documents:
                now = timezone.now()
                if now >= doc.date_published + timedelta(days = doc.owner.group.valid_time):
                    doc.delete()
    return redirect("user_home")`

**cron.yml:**

```
version: 1
cron:
    - name: "delete_expired_files"         
url: "http://networksapp.elasticbeanstalk.com/networks_app/delete_expired_files"
schedule: "* * * * *"
```

However, it prints this on the log file at the access_log part :
`"POST /myapp/management/commands/delete_expired_files HTTP/1.1" 500 124709 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.0"`

This is the log file I am accessing so far:
[Log file content](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1l43uPtkMooywaH5L-Hk4kpv81faeJQFuNnVDieGIDXE/edit?usp=sharing)

Why is it? How can I fix it?
Thank you so much.

Comment: As I mentioned here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658484/eb-worker-cron-yaml-is-not-authorized-to-perform-dynamodbupdateitem/30670603?noredirect=1#comment57440790_30670603), try to log more information in your application wherever you implement delete_expired_files.

Comment: It looks like sqsd is posting to your apache proxy server on the python container which is forwarding information to your django app and the app is erroring out and hence the proxy is throwing an HTTP 500 response code to the worker tier daemon.

Comment: Here is a tutorial on building Django apps with Elastic Beanstalk: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

Comment: AFAIK you are still trying to run management command (an executable). This is not the way AWS cronjob is meant to work. You have to define an **HTTP endpoint** that the SQS will call using HTTP POST. So, instead of defining a **management command**, you should create **a Django view with proper urls** and specify the view's URL in the `cron.yaml` file (something like /cron/delete-expired-files). Your app should listen for HTTP POST on http://localhost:[port]/cron/delete-expired-files which the AWS SQS will call.

Comment: it works when I access the url in my browser, but it doesn't works automatically. I've edited the question, added the cron.yaml and the views.py code... When I access the log of  the worker environment it gives me the error: `"POST /http://networksapp.elasticbeanstalk.com/networks_app/delete_expired_files HTTP/1.1" 500 127057 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.0"`. When I access the code of the host environment, it gives me this: `"GET /networks_app/delete_expired_files HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"`

Comment: The error now is 403, I believe I'm getting close to solve this. I've created a new environment identical to the host one and it's the new worker. My app is running in two environments still. I've changed some stuff and now I'm getting `"POST /networks_app/delete_expired_files HTTP/1.1" 403 2629 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.0"`. It's a permission issue now.